# Using rvest to scrape a website - Selecting html node?

Tags: r, quantmod, rvest

I have a question about my latest r vest scrape.

I want to scrape this page (and some other stocks as well):
http://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AA&ty=c&p=d&b=1

I need a list of the Market Capital, which is the first box in the second line.
This list should contain approx 50-100 stocks.

I am using rvest for that.

```
library(rvest)

html = read_html("http://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=A")

cast = html_nodes(html, "table-dark-row")
```

The problem is, I can not get around the html_nodes.
Any idea about how to find out the correct node for the html_nodes?

I am using firebug/firefinder to check out the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want because I cannot find a list with aprox. 50-100 stocks.

But for what is worth, using [SelectorGadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) I came up with this node .table-dark-row:nth-child(2) .snapshot-td2:nth-child(2), to select the Market Cap (first box in the second line of this page  http://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AA&ty=c&p=d&b=1).

```
> library(rvest)
> 
> html = read_html("http://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AA&ty=c&p=d&b=1")
> 
> cast = html_nodes(html, ".table-dark-row:nth-child(2) .snapshot-td2:nth-child(2)")
> cast
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <td width="8%" class="snapshot-td2" align="left">\n  <b>11.58B</b>\n</td>
>
```

If this is not exactly what you want, just use SelectorGadget to locate what you want.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT :**

Here complete solution:

```
library(rvest)

html = read_html("http://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AA&ty=c&p=d&b=1")

cast = html_nodes(html, ".table-dark-row:nth-child(2) .snapshot-td2:nth-child(2)")

html_text(cast) %>%
    gsub(pattern = "B", replacement = "") %>%
    as.numeric()
```

Comment: That one seems quite legit. I need to figure out how to extract the numbers from the string.

Comment: use the function `html_text()` from the very same `rvest` package. `html_text(cast)` gives you "12.76B", then, to convert it to numeric you would need to get rid of the B (which I have no idea what it means). I edited to answer. Check the full solution there.