# How to do web scraping of key stats from FinViz tables per stock?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, quantmod, quandl

Is anyone experienced in scraping data with R?

I would like to extract the corresponding data for given stocks. I did this in the following way:

```
library(XML)

stocks <- c("AAPL","MSFT")

for (s in stocks) {
  url <- paste0("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=", s)
  webpage <- readLines(url)
  html <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, useInternalNodes = TRUE, asText = TRUE)
  tableNodes <- getNodeSet(html, "//table")

  # ASSIGN TO STOCK NAMED DFS
  assign(s, readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[9]], 
                          header= c("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", "data6",
                                    "data7", "data8", "data9", "data10", "data11", "data12")))

  # ADD COLUMN TO IDENTIFY STOCK 
  df <- get(s)
  df['stock'] <- s
  assign(s, df)
}

# COMBINE ALL STOCK DATA 
stockdatalist <- cbind(mget(stocks))
stockdata <- do.call(rbind, stockdatalist)
# MOVE STOCK ID TO FIRST COLUMN
stockdata <- stockdata[, c(ncol(stockdata), 1:ncol(stockdata)-1)]
```

The problem, however, is that I have obtained it in the wrong format:

```
  stock      data1       data2       data3 data4       data5  data6         data7  data8        data9          data10       data11 data12
1  AAPL      Index DJIA S&P500         P/E 16.13   EPS (ttm)  10.22   Insider Own  0.06% Shs Outstand           5.09B    Perf Week -7.35%
2  AAPL Market Cap     839.87B Forward P/E 12.50  EPS next Y  13.20 Insider Trans -7.80%    Shs Float           5.07B   Perf Month -4.38%
3  AAPL     Income      53.13B         PEG  1.38  EPS next Q   2.71      Inst Own 63.20%  Short Float           1.16% Perf Quarter -5.40%
4  AAPL      Sales     239.18B         P/S  3.51  EPS this Y 10.80%    Inst Trans  0.98%  Short Ratio            1.60  Perf Half Y  7.53%
5  AAPL    Book/sh       27.42         P/B  6.02  EPS next Y 14.97%           ROA 13.80% Target Price          192.54    Perf Year 17.05%
6  AAPL    Cash/sh       15.15         P/C 10.89 EPS next 5Y 11.68%           ROE 37.40%    52W Range 138.62 - 183.50     Perf YTD -2.54%
```

What I would like to do is that a certain stock only appears once in the row name and that the datanames are then displayed as column names where the columns then contain the corresponding numbers...

Comment: Your question is similar to (although not an exact duplicate of) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490717/using-rvest-to-scrape-a-website-selecting-html-node -- check over there and see if that helps. Advice: use `rvest` for scraping.

Comment: @mysteRious , I did see the particular post before posting, however it did not help me further with my problem... :(

Comment: Oh, I finally see what it is you're trying to do. Will work on it.

Comment: @mysteRious The goal is to get it in some kind of standard wide format.. in order to make the data analysis easier..

Answer (score 1):

This is not super elegant but it gets the job done. It relies on the knowledge that the data you're interested in is in the 6th `table` on this page:

```
library(rvest)
url <- read_html("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=AAPL")
tables <- html_nodes(url,"table")
scraped <- tables %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[6] %>% 
    html_table(fill=TRUE) %>% data.frame()
```

This yields data that looks like:

```
> str(scraped)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ X1 : chr  "Index" "Market Cap" "Income" "Sales" ...
 $ X2 : chr  "DJIA S&P500" "839.87B" "53.13B" "239.18B" ...
 $ X3 : chr  "P/E" "Forward P/E" "PEG" "P/S" ...
 $ X4 : chr  "16.13" "12.50" "1.38" "3.51" ...
... the rest is truncated
```

You can get the format you want using `stack`:

```
new_df <- as.data.frame(scraped[, seq(from=2, to=ncol(scraped), by=2)])
new_labels <- as.data.frame(scraped[, seq(from=1, to=ncol(scraped), by=2)])
results_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(stack(new_labels),stack(new_df))[,c(1,3)])
names(results_df) <- c("stock","AAPL")
```

This provides a `results_df` that looks like this, which contains all 72 variable/value pairs:

```
> head(results_df)
    Variable       Value
1      Index DJIA S&P500
2 Market Cap     839.87B
3     Income      53.13B
4      Sales     239.18B
5    Book/sh       27.42
6    Cash/sh       15.15
```

Then you can transpose it and add stock labels with `as.data.frame(t(rbind(c("stock","AAPL"),results_df)))` .